# Generating a random graph with a given # of edges and nodes

Tags: java, random

I want to generate a random graph for a given number of nodes + edges. When I run it, it returns an edgelist of all zeroes (e.g. if I run it with five nodes and edges, it returns five pairs of zeroes as the edgelist). Is there something wrong with this part of the code that would be causing that?

```
public GraphEdgeList(int nNodes, int nEdges) {
    if (nNodes != 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < nEdges; i++){
            int u = (int) Math.random()* nNodes;
            int v = (int) Math.random()* nNodes;
            
            addEdge(u, v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider breaking it down to see what's happening, e.g., what's `(int) Math.random()`? What happens when you multiply that by `nNodes`? This might give you insight into what to try next.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to forget the exact rules on execution order, as in

```
int u = (int) Math.random()* nNodes;
```

Is it first compute `Math.random()* nNodes`, and then truncate the result to an integer, or is it first `(int) Math.random()`, and then multiply that integer it with `nNodes`? If you're unsure, place parentheses, then you don't have to remember the detailed rules:

```
int u = (int) (Math.random()* nNodes);
```

And, with your expression, the default execution rules first do `(int) Math.random()`. The `random()` result is a fractional value between 0 and 0.99999..., and casting it to int always gives zero. Multiply that with `nNodes`, and it's still zero - surely not what you had in mind.